# Multi file uploading not saving

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying for days now to wrap my head around this one but I just cant get it to work. I am new to php and am sure you guys might be able to assist or point out as to what I am doing wrong.

I have a form that needs to upload file to a certain directory and although the browsers progress bar shows that the files are uploading it still is not saved within the directory and also not captured within the table field in MySql.

The file with the multiple upload form:

```
     <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
 <form action="includes/add.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <th>Ad Warnings Documents</th>
 <tr>
 <td>Warning File 1</td>
 <td><input type="file" name="warning1" /></td>

 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>Warning File 2</td>
 <td><input type="file" name="warning2"  /></td>

 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>Warning File 3</td>
 <td><input type="file" name="warning3" /></td>
 </tr>

  <tr><td><input type="submit"  value="add"></form></td></tr>
 </table>

 </div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

The upload script:

```
            <?php
include 'core/init.php';
 // Connects to your Database 
include 'includes/overall/header.php';
error_reporting(1);

$connect_error = 'Sorry, we\'re experiencing connection problems.';
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password') or die($connect_error);
mysql_select_db('DB_Name') or die($connect_error);

  //This is the directory where images will be saved 
$target = "../files/empdocs/"; 
$target1 = $target . basename( $_FILES['warning1']['name']); 
$target2 = $target . basename( $_FILES['warning2']['name']);
$target3 = $target . basename( $_FILES['warning3']['name']);
 //This gets all the other information from the form 

 $warning1=mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['warning1']['name']); 
 $warning2=mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['warning2']['name']);
 $warning3=mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['warning3']['name']); 


  //Writes the information to the database 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ref_employees (`warning1`,`warning2`,`warning3`) 
VALUES ('$warning1', '$warning2', '$warning3')")  or die(mysql_error());
  //Writes the file to the server 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning1']['tmp_name'], $target1))
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['warning1']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning2']['tmp_name'], $target2))
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['warning2']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning3']['tmp_name'], $target3))
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['warning3']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
 //Tells you if its all ok 

 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 

 }
 ?>

 <?php
include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Your code is not well written and your question lacks information. I think you should try to include the exact part of the uploading process because right now there are different sections in your code.

Comment: I have made the amendment and hope it is what you were looking form.

The first part being the form

The second part being the Upload file add.php

Comment: First, your `mysql_*` functions are all deprecated and you should use either **mysqli** or an interface like **PDO**. Second, if there is any error or message you should write it too because now I can go for any kind of guess. This way, community can help you.

Comment: I have made some changes to my file and got it to upload the file although I am receiving the error specified in the code... "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file." the log file does not show any errors for the relevant process. I'm thinking the "echo sorry" might be because there are more than one field? I still doesn't seem to capture the file names within the db though...

Comment: There are two possible issues. For your database entry there might be a problem with your query. Write `mysql_query  ("INSERT INTO ref_employees VALUES ('$warning1', '$warning2', '$warning3')") or die(mysql_error());` to see whether there is any error or not. For uploading part, each file has an error field. At the part where you warn user about failure of upload you can `echo` errors like `echo $_FILES['warning1']['error']`. This will print a number for that file's error and you can refer to PHP manual to find that error's context. You should check all of your file fields for this.

Comment: Tried and tested got "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified the columns names in your SQL statement and probably the values count are more or less than columns count. I recommend you to specify all necessary columns names for every `INSERT` syntax from now on.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ref_employees (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`) 
VALUES ('$warning1', '$warning2', '$warning3')") ;
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for helping with such a minor stupid mistake. Thank you